# Does GUI program need Standard Streams?

Tags: user-interface, stream, unix

I read about [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). My understanding is old fashioned programs that don't have GUI need some kind of user interface, too. So Operating System provide each of them with a console window, and the console window's out/input/err stream was mapped to the program's standard input/output/error stream. And thus these programs are called console application. And this mappings couldn't be modified by the programmer.

I am wondering, if my understanding above is correct, does GUI program have these standard streams also? I don't think it's necessary since GUI itself is a good user interface.

Comment: Old fashioned; haha. I guess that makes me an old-fashioned programmer. :)

Comment: @guns - Me too, and every other programmer writing server-side applications

Comment: Pedantic note - GUI is not a user interface, it's a term describing a user interface.  Windows is a GUI.  A text-based menu system on UNIX is a GUI.

Comment: Another pednantic note: stdout/stdin/stderr can be remapped to whatever destination you like -- in shell using > | or <, and in C using dup2 or freopen

Comment: Thanks, guys. I apologize for my word mis-use. and Thanks for your clarification.  8^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quoting the bottom of the article you linked to:

> Graphical user interfaces (GUIs)
> rarely make use of the standard
> streams.
>
> Some GUI programs, primarily on Unix,
> still write debug information to
> standard error.
>
> Others may take files to operate from
> standard in, for example many Unix
> media players do so.

Therefore from the above quotes, you can see that yes they do, although they're rarely used.

> "And this mappings couldn't be
> modified by the programmer."

This is incorrect - certainly on UNIX they can be - not sure about Windows.  For example, you can close the standard output stream and redirect it to a file stream to get the output written to a file.

Answer (score 1):

- This varies a lot based on your OS. Some will create a console if you run a "command line" app, some will connect the standard streams to the same streams as the process that started the program had.
- You typically *can* change the stdout/in/err streams, it's very common to connect them to something else than the console in which they were run, like a pipe or file.
- GUI programs typically have the stdout/err/in streams as well.
- GUI programs rarly use those streams, perhaps except for debugging printfs during development.
- GUI programs might redirect those streams to /dev/null or something similar that just discards data written to it.

Comment: Thanks, nos. If I understand it right. A program has stdout/in/err and these threams can be connected to the console's out/in/err or not. Suppose I don't make such connection, can I write directly to the stdout stream of a program? could you give me some sample code snippet? C# would be better...  Many thanks.